# Invertible Matrix and Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition of two square matrices $A,B$ are similar is that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ s.t. $B=P^{-1}AP$. When the given $V$ is an inner product space then there is also something called orthogonally similar. Given $F=\mathbb R$, The orthogonal matrix can be considered as rotation about the origin, so I wonder what's the invertible matrix $P$ in the case of similar? If it's not a rotation what should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal matrix can also represent a symmetry with respect to some axis. Determinant of orthogonal matrix can be either $1$ or $-1$. Positive determinant means it represents a rotation, negative determinant means it represents a symmetry. Therefore, an orthogonal matrix is necessarily invertible.

Two matrices $A, B$ are said to be **orthogonally similar**, if there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$, such that: $B = P^{-1}AP$.

Orthogonal similarity implies ordinary similarity, the converse most likely doesn't hold.

Comment: Your answer helps but sorry I cannot vote your answer(rep<15). And I'm thinking about your determinant $-1$ case, does that mean like that something "flip" on the plane so a counter-clockwise route becomes clockwise?

Comment: Basically, yes. Symmetry with respect to some line maps every point to the other side of the line, preserving the distance.